# Jquery show number within div in alert

Tags: jquery, html, numbers, show

**hi**

i want to  **show number with in Div in alert** like this

```
<script> 
var sec = $('#demo').html();
alert(sec);
</script> 
<div id="demo">100</div>
```

code most be show  **100**  number

but it also  **null**  or  **undefined**  or  **zero**  when i use

```
size(); , text(); , html(); , length;
```

**edit :**  I got my problem . my jquery is v1.7.1 And it seems has problem with this . so i upgraded my jquery to v1.9.1 and my code works fine . Thank you for all the answers

Comment: As you have posted, you already have a number inside a `<div>`, now, *"I want to show number with in Div"* it's quite not understandable and self explanatory. Can you please improve your question?

Comment: completed. thanks for your reminder

Comment: var temp = $(#demo).text() will give you  its text

Comment: but its not . It is weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Set

This techniques will **set** (place) a number inside an empty `<div id="demo"></div>`

```
$('#demo').text(100);      // Overwrite with new content
$('#demo').html(100);      // Overwrites + you can insert raw (string) HTML. 
$('#demo').append(100);    // Keeps content and appends to element
$('#demo').prepend(100);   // Keeps content and prepends to element
$('#demo')[0].textContent = "100"; // jQ/JS, Overwrite with Text Content
$('#demo')[0].innerHTML = "100";   // jQ/JS, Overwrite with HTML
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 100 ; // Pure JS example
```

http://jsbin.com/eyuhay/10/edit

## Get

This techniques will **get** a desired content (*100*) out of your `<div id="demo">100</div>`

```
var number = $('#demo').text();            // jQ                  
var number = $('#demo').html();            // jQ
var number = $('#demo')[0].innerHTML;      // jQ/JS
var number = $('#demo').get(0).innerHTML;  // jQ/JS using .get(0) instead of [0]
var number = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;   // pure JS
var number = document.getElementById('demo').textContent; // pure JS
```

http://jsbin.com/eyuhay/11/edit

## .size(), length

`.size()` is a jQuery Method to retrieve the number of elements in our object array.
`.length` is a native JS method to get the... length <kbd>**:-D**</kbd>

Additionally take a look at : http://jsbin.com/eyuhay/6/edit :

```
alert( number.length );      // 3, cause 100 has 3 digits
alert( $('#demo').size()  ); // 1, Use size() on Elements
alert( $('#demo').length );  // 1, cause only 1 element #ID
```

- wrap always your code into `document ready function`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) { 
    // DOM is now read and ready to be manipulated
    /* code here */
} );
```

- Or place your `<script></script>` tags before `</body>`

Comment: This is useful information, but doesn't really answer the question; the code shown should already work fine (but it's in the wrong place).

Comment: @Jack nice, now I've seen that the OP modified the Q code. lol I need a coffee +1 to you

Answer (score 1):

Your current code should work fine, except that it's in the wrong order:

```
<div id="demo">100</div>
<script> 
var sec = $('#demo').html();
alert(sec);
</script>
```

The element should be available in the DOM *before* you can run the script. Alternatively, you should let the code run as part of the DOM ready event handler:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    alert($('#demo').html());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on clarifications, the problem is your script need to be executed in dom ready.

```
<script> 
    jQuery(function($){
        var sec = $('#demo').html();
        alert(sec);
    });
</script> 
<div id="demo">100</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3eERP/)

Comment: @user2198380 do you want to set the number in the `div` or read the value from the `div`

Comment: i want to read value from the div and show it in alert. i complete my question

Comment: @user2198380 in that case you have to use `alert($('#demo').text())`

Comment: It's about the part of my jquery ? because i tested your code and it most be work but didnt show alert